# Execute GraphQL-Mutation on Button-Click

Tags: reactjs, button, graphql, jsx, react-apollo

I'm trying to wire a [GraphQL-mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/) to a button inside my React-app. So far I have tried to do it like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  ...
  
  const [useTestProgramMutation, {data, loading, error}] = 
  useMutation(TESTPROGRAM_MUTATION);

  ...
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => useTestProgramMutation({
        variables: {
          examinationOrderId: order_id,
          testProgramId: testProgram.id
        }
      })}>
        Click me!
      </button>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

However compilation fails with the error:

```
React Hook "useTestProgramMutation" cannot be called inside a callback.
React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React
Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

However, I don't really understand the error. Where do I have to call the function then?

Comment: This looks correct to me. Can you show the whole definition of the component, not just snippets of the body?

Comment: Also, just for convention, it should probably be `testProgramMutation` instead of `useTestProgramMutation` because that **is** the mutation, not another hook. Thats also the pattern in the documentation you are following.

Comment: I changed the code above to reflect the buttons position in the component. Does that already help you?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to rename it to something other than "Component" since there is already a `React.Component` and maybe thats conflicting somewhere else in the code.

Comment: "Component" was a fictional name. I'm sorry, that I didn't provide code, that was more correct, but unfortunately the code is confidential. I've found an answer though. Will post it momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the function, that is returned by `useMutation` seems to have done the trick. I changed it from `useTestProgramMutation` to `testProgramMutation`.

It compiles now. If anyone has a clue why that is, I would be highly interested to know.

Comment: simply, name starting with `use` is recognized as hook?

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation on this? Didn't find any

Comment: "A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.". There we have it. Thank you!